# Selecting from table where timestamp between X doesn't return all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database table with different records and they all have timestamp with them.

When I want to get a certain month (for example April) records is use following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `water` 
WHERE timestamp >= DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d') 
  AND timestamp <= DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-30', '%Y-%m-%d') 
  AND watercar='JV03' 
ORDER by timestamp DESC
```

It will return me records which  timestamp is between 01.04.2020-29.04.2020   but it misses the last day of april 30.04.2020 record.

I also tried >= <= and between operators, same issue although the record does exist.

What am I missing?

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nWFFZmUt7FM17c98DXRRQw/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `water` 
WHERE timestamp between DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-30', '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') AND watercar='JV03' 
ORDER by timestamp DESC
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM `water` 
WHERE DATE(timestamp) between DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-30', '%Y-%m-%d') AND watercar='JV03' 
ORDER by timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there should be no need to use `date_format)`.  MySQL should understand dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Second, do not use `between` with date/time values.  Instead, to get everything in April, use:

```
where timestamp >= date('2020-04-01') and
      timestamp < date('2020-05-01')
```

This formulation works both when the column as a time component and when it does not.  So, I recommend it in all situation.

If you want to pass in the end date as a parameter, you can use:

```
where timestamp >= :start_dt and
      timestamp < :end_dt + interval 1 day
```